# Only two distinct values of probabilities in Logistic regression output

Tags: r, classification, probability, logistic-regression, glm

I am running a logistic regression in R and extracting the predicted probabilities for a test data of about 15,000 rows using

```
predict(modelglm, test_data, type = "prob")
```

I was expecting to get various values of probabilities between 0 and 1 but instead there were only two distinct values of probabilities. All the probabilities were either 1 or 2.220446e-16 (which is practically equal to zero).  Just in effect I am getting a binary classification instead of probabilities.

Why is this happening?

Comment: what is `class(modelglm)`? With a regular `glm(...,family="binomial")`, using `type="prob"` gives an error (''arg' should be one of “link”, “response”, “terms”'). More generally, you should give us a [mcve]: I know you said your data are confidential, but that shouldn't prevent you from constructing a similar example ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not provide a reproducible example, but I believe the `type` parameter is wrong. Use "response" instead "prob".

```
predict(modelglm, test_data, type="response")
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a possibility that the explanatory variables explain too much. F.ex if in every case that the dependent variable is true, B2 is 1, and for every case that the dependent variable is false, B2 is 0, then the model can get too good, and predicts only 0 or 1 (R usually gives 2.220446e-16 and 1 like you stated).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).